# KDB select query and vs function

Tags: kdb

Just curious what does this KX code do:

```
" " {`$first x vs y}/: column
```

it is part of the large KX query which is used after in the update statement.

What is `x vs y` and where they come from and what `/:` does together with `" "` on the left side?

the whole query looks like this:

```
select count i by date, somecolumn from update somecolumn:(" " {`$first x vs y}/: othercolumn) from select from some_table
```

What is `x vs y` and where they come from and what `/:` does together with `" "` on the left side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/:` is an [adverb](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/) which means '[each right](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-right)'.

One simple example is using the `,` with `/:` to join the left item to each of the right items:

```
q)1 2 3,/:4 5 6
1 2 3 4    / 1 2 3 join with 4
1 2 3 5    / 1 2 3 join with 5
1 2 3 6    / 1 2 3 join with 6
```

`vs` is '[vector scalar](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#vs)' which in your case separate strings from a delimiter " ".

```
q)" " vs "1 2 3"
,"1"
,"2"
,"3"
```

`` {`$first x vs y} `` is a function that cut `y` with `x`, take the first of the result and cast it to a symbol:

```
q){`$first x vs y}[" ";"1 2 3"]
`1
```

Combine them all together, `` " " {`$first x vs y}/: column `` means cut each of the strings in 'column' with " ", take the first of each results and cast them to symbols:

```
q)update res:" "{`$first x vs y}/:test from ([]test:("1 2 3";"4 5 6"))
test    res
-----------
"1 2 3" 1
"4 5 6" 4
```

Answer (score 1):

In simple words: It takes first value before space  from a string  and cast it to symbol.

Ex: Input "Hello World" will give output `Hello

```
 q> {`$first  x vs y}  [" ";"Hello World"]
```

Output: `Hello

You can test it with simple list (column in your query will be replaced by actual list from table corresponding to that column )

```
  q>  " "{`$first  x vs y}/: ("hello world" ; "test program")
```

output: `hello`test

Comparing this to ex1,  " " is moved to start which is due to syntax of   "each right(/:)"

Alternate simpler version of this is:

```
   q){`$first   " "  vs x } each ("hello world" ; "test program")
```

WooiKent has already explained the functions. But here are some references:

**Each-Right(/:)  :** It is a loop which iterates over values of right list

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-right

**vs(Vector From Scalar):** Break a string on some delimiter

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/casting/#vs

In your query, it takes a column whose type is  string as input. For each element(row) of that column, takes first value before space. Finally cast that value to symbol.